# Most suitable collection for multithreading requests?

Tags: .net, linq, multithreading

I have ~10,000 records would like to keep in a collection in memory and execute LINQ queries against it.  This collection should be available for all the users in the application domain and can access concurrently. I’m looking for a .NET collection that supports multithreading can query asynchronously and efficiently without any threading issues.  Any suggestions on deciding a collection for this?

Sorry - It is only to read, no updates. And it should NOT be in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to update it? If not, any of the usual suspects (e.g. `List<T>` or an array) should be fine. If there's a natural key you want to look things up by, you may want to use a dictionary instead, but if it's really "just a collection" then a list should be fine.

EDIT: It looks like the rest of this answer is irrelevant to this particular question, but I'll leave it here for others with slightly different requirements.

If you *do* need to update it - and if you're able to use .NET 4 - you should at least *consider* [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx). Bear in mind that it's unordered, and that if you iterate over it and modify the bag concurrently you won't see the changes (it's a snapshot, according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381960.aspx)), but if that's okay, it may well be what you're after.

If that doesn't quite do what you want, have a look at the other collections in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) - again, this is all for .NET 4.